# Undefined variable: message Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Eu estou com o seguinte problema no laravel na view ta me retormando  `$message` esta indefinida  no intanto a variavel  `$message` e padrão pelo menos como indica na documentação na parte de validação de forms blade

```
 @error('cpf_cnpj')
 <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
 </span>
 @enderror
```

> Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu posso esta solucionado este erro?

Comment: onde diz na documentação que $message sempre está disponível?

Comment: Creio que você entendeu algo errado 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#passing-data-to-views
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#named-error-bags

Comment: Ao retornar para a view você não está informando a `$message`, tem como mostra mais informação da sua função pra fazer login ?

Comment: no caso se usei o make:auth para criar os templates e os controlles.

Comment: Qual a versão do Laravel?

Comment: Tenta utilizar o `$errors->all()` pra pegar todos os erros, ai vc faz um `foreach` e exibi cada um.

Comment: @kayo Bruno o que  aconteceu foi o seguinte agente tava trabalhando na versão 6 do laravel e tava funcionando tudo certo daí agente vou para a 5.8 daí  o Blade parou de reconhecer as validações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faz um teste com essa solução:

```
@if($error->has('cpf_cnpj'))
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
     <strong>{{ $error->first('cpf_cnpj')}}</strong>
 </span>
@endif
```